# Not analyzed field in elastic search NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I need to declare a field of an elastic search document as NOT ANALYZED since I want to match it using a wildcard query.

How can I accomplish this using NEST 2.4.5?

I've tried the [String(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)] but it seems that it doesn't work...

In order to push document on ES I'm using the following code to describe the ES document:

```
public class mydoc
{
    private string _md5;  
    private string _filename;  
    private string _file_path;  
    private string _type; 
    private string _data_json; //<--- this should be NOT ANALYZED
    private DateTime _date;  

    [JsonConstructor]
    public mydoc(string md5, string filename, string file_path, string type, string data_json, DateTime date)
    {
        this._md5 = md5;
        this._filename = filename;
        this._file_path = file_path;
        this._type = type;
        this._data_json = data_json;
        this._date = date;  
    }
}

/* GETTER AND SETTER HERE */
```

And this in order to push it inside the ES:

```
public mydocPutInfo(string md5, string filename, string base_64 , string type, string data_json)
    {
        mydoc pfd = new mydoc(md5, filename, base_64, type, metadata_json, DateTime.Now);
        string json = SerializeInfo(pfd);

        var client = ESConnector.GetESClient();

            var index = client.Index(pfd, i => i
            .Index(EL_MY_INDEX)
            .Type(EL_MY_TYPE)
            .Id(md5.ToString())           
            );

        return pfd;
    }
```

Comment: What does the mapping for `mydoc` look like in Elasticsearch? How or where are you telling Elasticsearch about the explicit mapping for `mydoc`?

Comment: Hi Russ, I'm kind of new in using NEST, I thought that it derives the mapping directly from the attributes in the class mydoc using the  [String(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)] over the field data_json. Is this wrong? Inside ES  'mydoc' is not marked as "not_analyzed".

Comment: It will derive the mapping from the attributes, but you still need to let Elasticsearch know about the mapping by calling `.AutoMap()` either at index creation or before you index the first document. Take a look at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/auto-map.html